# Qt is not available error while compiling a wireshark plugin

Tags: qt, wireshark

I am trying to built a wireshark plugin code on my RHEL5 Virtual machine and while I am trying to compile it, I am getting the below error.

On `./configure` command , below is the error message I receive and the make file is not being generated.

```
checking for Qt5Core - version >= 4.6.0... no
checking for QtCore - version >= 4.6.0... no
configure: error: Qt is not available
```

Please advise on how to go about this error. I  have looked up for various rpm files and tried  installing them but none works!

Comment: Is this a programming question, or a question about installing some software from sources on a specific OS?

Answer (score 2):

Try installing below packages as stated in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/382444/qt-headers-and-libraries-not-found) answer. Worked for me.

```
libqt4-dev (4:4.8.2+dfsg-11)
libqt4-dev-bin (4:4.8.2+dfsg-11)
libqt4-opengl-dev (4:4.8.2+dfsg-11)
libqtwebkit-dev (2.2.1-5)
qt4-linguist-tools (4:4.8.2+dfsg-11)
qt4-qmake (4:4.8.2+dfsg-11)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message you post is telling you that you need a version of Qt greater than or equal to 4.6.0. Since you are building software against Qt you will need the developer version of the package. There seems to be packages named qt47-devel that should be suitable.

Comment: I have tried installing qt47-devel using the rpm : qt47-devel-4.7.2-1_18.el6 RPM for x86_64 but I received the below error :

Comment: It says I have a lot of missing dependencies.

Comment: @Sindhu The "el6" in the name shows that RPM is for RHEL6.