# Qt is not available error while compiling a wireshark 1.12

Tags: qt, wireshark

Same issue at another topic, you can reference follow link:

[Qt is not available error while compiling a wireshark plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23962244/qt-is-not-available-error-while-compiling-a-wireshark-plugin/25964775#25964775)

I have same issue on rhel6.3, and I download all qt47 rpm:

```
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  4282888 Sep 22 06:32 qt47-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 11458684 Sep 22 06:33 qt47-devel-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root    54076 Sep 22 06:32 qt47-sqlite-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  5374988 Sep 22 06:33 qt47-webkit-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 13297200 Sep 22 06:34 qt47-x11-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

When install that, report conflict with libjpeg-turbo:

```
[root@frank frank]# yum localinstall qt47*
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, security, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity
Setting up Local Package Process
Examining qt47-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64.rpm: 1:qt47-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64
Marking qt47-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining qt47-devel-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64.rpm: 1:qt47-devel-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64
Marking qt47-devel-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining qt47-sqlite-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64.rpm: 1:qt47-sqlite-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64
Marking qt47-sqlite-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining qt47-webkit-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64.rpm: 1:qt47-webkit-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64
Marking qt47-webkit-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining qt47-x11-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64.rpm: 1:qt47-x11-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64
Marking qt47-x11-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package qt47.x86_64 1:4.7.1-3_15.el6 will be installed
---> Package qt47-devel.x86_64 1:4.7.1-3_15.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libGL-devel for package: 1:qt47-devel-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libGLU-devel for package: 1:qt47-devel-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libICE-devel for package: 1:qt47-devel-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libSM-devel for package: 1:qt47-devel-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libX11-devel for package: 1:qt47-devel-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXcursor-devel for package: 1:qt47-devel-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXext-devel for package: 1:qt47-devel-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXfixes-devel for package: 1:qt47-devel-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXft-devel for package: 1:qt47-devel-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXi-devel for package: 1:qt47-devel-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXinerama-devel for package: 1:qt47-devel-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXrandr-devel for package: 1:qt47-devel-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXrender-devel for package: 1:qt47-devel-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXt-devel for package: 1:qt47-devel-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXv-devel for package: 1:qt47-devel-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libjpeg-devel for package: 1:qt47-devel-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpng-devel for package: 1:qt47-devel-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: xorg-x11-proto-devel for package: 1:qt47-devel-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64
---> Package qt47-sqlite.x86_64 1:4.7.1-3_15.el6 will be installed
---> Package qt47-webkit.x86_64 1:4.7.1-3_15.el6 will be installed
---> Package qt47-x11.x86_64 1:4.7.1-3_15.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: phonon-backend(x86-64) >= 4.3 for package: 1:qt47-x11-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libICE-devel.x86_64 0:1.0.6-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package libSM-devel.x86_64 0:1.1.0-7.1.el6 will be installed
---> Package libX11-devel.x86_64 0:1.3-2.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: pkgconfig(xcb) >= 1.1.92 for package: libX11-devel-1.3-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: pkgconfig(xcb) for package: libX11-devel-1.3-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXdmcp-devel for package: libX11-devel-1.3-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXau-devel for package: libX11-devel-1.3-2.el6.x86_64
---> Package libXcursor-devel.x86_64 0:1.1.10-2.el6 will be installed
---> Package libXext-devel.x86_64 0:1.1-3.el6 will be installed
---> Package libXfixes-devel.x86_64 0:4.0.4-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package libXft-devel.x86_64 0:2.1.13-4.1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: freetype-devel >= 2.1.9-2 for package: libXft-devel-2.1.13-4.1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: fontconfig-devel >= 2.2-1 for package: libXft-devel-2.1.13-4.1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: pkgconfig(freetype2) for package: libXft-devel-2.1.13-4.1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: pkgconfig(fontconfig) for package: libXft-devel-2.1.13-4.1.el6.x86_64
---> Package libXi-devel.x86_64 0:1.3-3.el6 will be installed
---> Package libXinerama-devel.x86_64 0:1.1-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package libXrandr-devel.x86_64 0:1.3.0-4.el6 will be installed
---> Package libXrender-devel.x86_64 0:0.9.5-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package libXt-devel.x86_64 0:1.0.7-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package libXv-devel.x86_64 0:1.0.5-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package libjpeg-devel.x86_64 0:6b-46.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libjpeg = 6b-46.el6 for package: libjpeg-devel-6b-46.el6.x86_64
---> Package libpng-devel.x86_64 2:1.2.49-1.el6_2 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: zlib-devel for package: 2:libpng-devel-1.2.49-1.el6_2.x86_64
---> Package mesa-libGL-devel.x86_64 0:7.11-5.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: pkgconfig(libdrm) >= 2.4.24 for package: mesa-libGL-devel-7.11-5.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: pkgconfig(xxf86vm) for package: mesa-libGL-devel-7.11-5.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: pkgconfig(xdamage) for package: mesa-libGL-devel-7.11-5.el6.x86_64
---> Package mesa-libGLU-devel.x86_64 0:7.11-5.el6 will be installed
---> Package phonon-backend-gstreamer.x86_64 1:4.6.2-24.el6 will be installed
---> Package xorg-x11-proto-devel.noarch 0:7.6-13.el6 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package fontconfig-devel.x86_64 0:2.8.0-3.el6 will be installed
---> Package freetype-devel.x86_64 0:2.3.11-6.el6_2.9 will be installed
---> Package libXau-devel.x86_64 0:1.0.5-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package libXdamage-devel.x86_64 0:1.1.2-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package libXdmcp-devel.x86_64 0:1.0.3-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package libXxf86vm-devel.x86_64 0:1.1.0-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package libdrm-devel.x86_64 0:2.4.25-2.el6 will be installed
---> Package libjpeg.x86_64 0:6b-46.el6 will be installed
---> Package libxcb-devel.x86_64 0:1.5-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package zlib-devel.x86_64 0:1.2.3-27.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

==============================================================================================================
 Package                      Arch       Version                 Repository                              Size
==============================================================================================================
Installing:
 qt47                         x86_64     1:4.7.1-3_15.el6        /qt47-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64             15 M
 qt47-devel                   x86_64     1:4.7.1-3_15.el6        /qt47-devel-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64       33 M
 qt47-sqlite                  x86_64     1:4.7.1-3_15.el6        /qt47-sqlite-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64      49 k
 qt47-webkit                  x86_64     1:4.7.1-3_15.el6        /qt47-webkit-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64      20 M
 qt47-x11                     x86_64     1:4.7.1-3_15.el6        /qt47-x11-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64         34 M
Installing for dependencies:
 fontconfig-devel             x86_64     2.8.0-3.el6             frank-source                           209 k
 freetype-devel               x86_64     2.3.11-6.el6_2.9        frank-source                           364 k
 libICE-devel                 x86_64     1.0.6-1.el6             frank-source                            15 k
 libSM-devel                  x86_64     1.1.0-7.1.el6           frank-source                            12 k
 libX11-devel                 x86_64     1.3-2.el6               frank-source                           1.0 M
 libXau-devel                 x86_64     1.0.5-1.el6             frank-source                            13 k
 libXcursor-devel             x86_64     1.1.10-2.el6            frank-source                            21 k
 libXdamage-devel             x86_64     1.1.2-1.el6             frank-source                           8.8 k
 libXdmcp-devel               x86_64     1.0.3-1.el6             frank-source                           9.6 k
 libXext-devel                x86_64     1.1-3.el6               frank-source                            78 k
 libXfixes-devel              x86_64     4.0.4-1.el6             frank-source                            11 k
 libXft-devel                 x86_64     2.1.13-4.1.el6          frank-source                            18 k
 libXi-devel                  x86_64     1.3-3.el6               frank-source                            93 k
 libXinerama-devel            x86_64     1.1-1.el6               frank-source                            12 k
 libXrandr-devel              x86_64     1.3.0-4.el6             frank-source                            19 k
 libXrender-devel             x86_64     0.9.5-1.el6             frank-source                            15 k
 libXt-devel                  x86_64     1.0.7-1.el6             frank-source                           326 k
 libXv-devel                  x86_64     1.0.5-1.el6             frank-source                            38 k
 libXxf86vm-devel             x86_64     1.1.0-1.el6             frank-source                            17 k
 libdrm-devel                 x86_64     2.4.25-2.el6            frank-source                            65 k
 libjpeg                      x86_64     6b-46.el6               frank-source                           134 k
 libjpeg-devel                x86_64     6b-46.el6               frank-source                           100 k
 libpng-devel                 x86_64     2:1.2.49-1.el6_2        frank-source                           112 k
 libxcb-devel                 x86_64     1.5-1.el6               frank-source                           139 k
 mesa-libGL-devel             x86_64     7.11-5.el6              frank-source                           494 k
 mesa-libGLU-devel            x86_64     7.11-5.el6              frank-source                           110 k
 phonon-backend-gstreamer     x86_64     1:4.6.2-24.el6          frank-source                           126 k
 xorg-x11-proto-devel         noarch     7.6-13.el6              frank-source                           303 k
 zlib-devel                   x86_64     1.2.3-27.el6            frank-source                            44 k

Transaction Summary
==============================================================================================================
Install      34 Package(s)

Total size: 106 M
Total download size: 3.9 M
Installed size: 113 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                                          12 MB/s | 3.9 MB     00:00     
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test


Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/bin/cjpeg from install of libjpeg-6b-46.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libjpeg-turbo-1.2.1-3.el6_5.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/djpeg from install of libjpeg-6b-46.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libjpeg-turbo-1.2.1-3.el6_5.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/jpegtran from install of libjpeg-6b-46.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libjpeg-turbo-1.2.1-3.el6_5.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/rdjpgcom from install of libjpeg-6b-46.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libjpeg-turbo-1.2.1-3.el6_5.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/wrjpgcom from install of libjpeg-6b-46.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libjpeg-turbo-1.2.1-3.el6_5.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/libjpeg.so.62.0.0 from install of libjpeg-6b-46.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libjpeg-turbo-1.2.1-3.el6_5.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/cjpeg.1.gz from install of libjpeg-6b-46.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libjpeg-turbo-1.2.1-3.el6_5.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/djpeg.1.gz from install of libjpeg-6b-46.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libjpeg-turbo-1.2.1-3.el6_5.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/jpegtran.1.gz from install of libjpeg-6b-46.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libjpeg-turbo-1.2.1-3.el6_5.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/rdjpgcom.1.gz from install of libjpeg-6b-46.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libjpeg-turbo-1.2.1-3.el6_5.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/qdbus from install of qt47-1:4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package qt-1:4.6.2-24.el6.x86_64

Error Summary
-------------

[root@frank frank]#
```

So I upgrade rhel6.3 to rhel6.5 by "yum update". After upgrade, I use same way to install qt47, found follow alarm:

```
Error: Package: libjpeg-turbo-devel-1.2.1-1.el6.x86_64 (frank-source)
           Requires: libjpeg-turbo(x86-64) = 1.2.1-1.el6
           Installed: libjpeg-turbo-1.2.1-3.el6_5.x86_64 (@/libjpeg-turbo-1.2.1-3.el6_5.x86_64)
               libjpeg-turbo(x86-64) = 1.2.1-3.el6_5
           Available: libjpeg-turbo-1.2.1-1.el6.x86_64 (frank-source)
               libjpeg-turbo(x86-64) = 1.2.1-1.el6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I using --skip-broken to workaround the problem, but when configure for wireshark, report same alarm...

```
[root@frank wireshark-1.12.1]# ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/wireshark
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether UID '0' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking whether GID '0' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking if gcc is Clang... no
checking if g++ is Clang... no
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1966080
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... no
checking if : is a manifest tool... no
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... no
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking for shl_load... no
checking for shl_load in -ldld... no
checking for dlopen... no
checking for dlopen in -ldl... yes
checking whether a program can dlopen itself... yes
checking whether a statically linked program can dlopen itself... yes
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... no
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... (cached) GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether g++ is a C++ compiler... yes
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking for python... /usr/bin/python
checking whether /usr/bin/python is Python 2.5 or later... yes
checking for bison... bison -y
checking for bison... /usr/bin/bison
checking for flex... flex
checking lex output file root... lex.yy
checking lex library... -lfl
checking whether yytext is a pointer... yes
checking for flex... /usr/bin/flex
checking for pod2man... /usr/bin/pod2man
checking for pod2html... /usr/bin/pod2html
checking for xdg-open... /usr/bin/xdg-open
checking for doxygen... no
checking for doxygen... no
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... no
checking for LIBGNUTLS... no
GnuTLS >= 3.1.10 not found 
checking for LIBGNUTLS... no
GnuTLS >= 1.2.0, < 3.0 not found 
GnuTLS with compatible license not found, disabling SSL decryption
checking for libgcrypt-config... no
checking for LIBGCRYPT - version >= 1.1.92... no
libgcrypt not found, disabling ipsec decryption
checking whether to use libnl for various network interface purposes... yes
checking for LIBNL3... no
checking for LIBNL2... no
checking for LIBNL1... no
checking if nl80211.h is new enough... yes
checking for NL80211_SET_CHANNEL... yes
checking for libsmi >= 2... not found
checking for a2x... no
checking for a2x... no
checking for elinks... no
checking for elinks... no
checking for fop... no
checking for fop... no
checking for lynx... no
checking for lynx... no
checking for w3m... no
checking for w3m... no
checking for xmllint... /usr/bin/xmllint
checking for xmllint... yes
checking for xsltproc... /usr/bin/xsltproc
checking for xsltproc... yes
checking for desktop-file-install... /usr/bin/desktop-file-install
checking for pkgproto... no
checking for pkgmk... no
checking for pkgtrans... no
checking for rpm... yes
checking to see if we can redefine _topdir... yes
checking for dpkg-buildpackage... no
checking for xcodebuild... no
checking for hdiutil... no
checking for bless... no
checking whether the compiler fails when given an unknown warning option... yes
checking whether the compiler fails when given an warning option not supported for C++... no, adding -Werror
checking whether we can add -Wall -W to CFLAGS... yes
checking whether we can add -Wall -W to CXXFLAGS... yes
checking whether we can add -Wextra to CFLAGS... yes
checking whether we can add -Wextra to CXXFLAGS... yes
checking whether we can add -Wdeclaration-after-statement to CFLAGS... yes
checking whether we can add -Wendif-labels to CFLAGS... yes
checking whether we can add -Wendif-labels to CXXFLAGS... yes
checking whether we can add -Wpointer-arith to CFLAGS... yes
checking whether we can add -Wpointer-arith to CXXFLAGS... yes
checking whether we can add -Wno-pointer-sign to CFLAGS... yes
checking whether we can add -Warray-bounds to CFLAGS... yes
checking whether we can add -Warray-bounds to CXXFLAGS... yes
checking whether we can add -Wformat-security to CFLAGS... yes
checking whether we can add -Wformat-security to CXXFLAGS... yes
checking whether we can add -fwrapv to CFLAGS... yes
checking whether we can add -fwrapv to CXXFLAGS... yes
checking whether we can add -fno-strict-overflow to CFLAGS... yes
checking whether we can add -fno-strict-overflow to CXXFLAGS... yes
checking whether we can add -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks to CFLAGS... yes
checking whether we can add -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks to CXXFLAGS... yes
checking whether we can add -Wold-style-definition to CFLAGS... yes
checking whether we can add -Wshorten-64-to-32 to CFLAGS... no
checking whether we can add -Wstrict-prototypes to CFLAGS... yes
checking whether we can add -Wjump-misses-init to CFLAGS... no
checking whether we can add -Wvla to CFLAGS... yes
checking whether we can add -Wvla to CXXFLAGS... yes
checking whether we can add -Waddress to CFLAGS... yes
checking whether we can add -Waddress to CXXFLAGS... yes
checking whether we can add -Wattributes to CFLAGS... yes
checking whether we can add -Wattributes to CXXFLAGS... yes
checking whether we can add -Wdiv-by-zero to CFLAGS... yes
checking whether we can add -Wdiv-by-zero to CXXFLAGS... yes
checking whether we can add -Wignored-qualifiers to CFLAGS... yes
checking whether we can add -Wignored-qualifiers to CXXFLAGS... yes
checking whether we can add -Wpragmas to CFLAGS... yes
checking whether we can add -Wpragmas to CXXFLAGS... yes
checking whether we can add -Wno-overlength-strings to CFLAGS... yes
checking whether we can add -Wno-overlength-strings to CXXFLAGS... yes
checking whether we can add -Wwrite-strings to CFLAGS... yes
checking whether we can add -Wwrite-strings to CXXFLAGS... yes
checking whether we can add -Wno-long-long to CFLAGS... yes
checking whether we can add -Wno-long-long to CXXFLAGS... yes
checking whether we can add -Wc++-compat to CFLAGS... yes
checking whether we can add -Wheader-guard to CFLAGS... no
checking whether we can add -Wheader-guard to CXXFLAGS... no
checking whether we can add -Wshadow to CFLAGS... yes
checking whether -Wshadow warns about variables in function declarations shadowing other variables... no
checking whether we can add -Wlogical-op to CFLAGS... yes
checking whether -Wlogical-op generates warnings from strchr()... yes
checking whether we can add -fexcess-precision=fast to CFLAGS... no
checking whether we can add -fexcess-precision=fast to CXXFLAGS... no
checking whether we can add -fvisibility=hidden to CFLAGS... yes
checking whether we can add -fvisibility=hidden to CXXFLAGS... yes
checking whether we can add -Wl,--as-needed to LDFLAGS... yes
checking whether we can add -fPIE to CFLAGS... yes
checking whether we can add -fPIE to CXXFLAGS... yes
checking whether we can add -fPIE -pie to LDFLAGS... yes
checking whether -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=... can be used (without generating a warning)... yes
checking whether we should treat compiler warnings as errors... no
checking for platform-specific compiler flags... none needed
checking for platform-specific linker flags... none needed
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
checking whether to use /usr/local for headers and libraries... yes
checking for sed... (cached) /bin/sed
checking for GNU sed as first sed in PATH... yes
checking if profile builds must be generated... no
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking for Qt5Core - version >= 4.6.0... no
checking for QtCore - version >= 4.6.0... no
configure: error: Qt is not available
```

Follow rpm -qa information:

```
[root@frank wireshark-1.12.1]# rpm -qa|grep qt
qt47-sqlite-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64
qt47-webkit-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64
qt47-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64
qt3-3.3.8b-30.el6.x86_64
qt47-x11-4.7.1-3_15.el6.x86_64
```

Why RHEL couldn't complete Wireshark configure?

Comment: You are more likely to get help on some RHEL forum. Getting help on building some existing software on some specific OS feels like it's not a programming question really, too.

Comment: `checking for Qt5Core` - probably it depends on Qt5 but complains about Qt >= 4.6. Also looks like your issue [already solved here](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/28105/qt-not-available-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After install "qt-devel" that in 6.5's CD-ROM, resolve qt issue, but report GTK alarm. I found Wireshark 1.12 need GTK3, that very badly, RHEL is older version GTK2. If upgrade to GTK3 that need more depend package... so I give up...

So I choose a easy way that upgrade to RHEL7 and checking again.
And install "gtk3-devel.x86_64", then compiler Wireshark, successful!
Then make/make install, normal work.
Thanks all guys kindly help for the issue.